# toggling in Angular Js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, toggle

I have a snippet done in Jquery. I need to Implement it in angular Js

```
$('.halfonoff').click(function(){  

 $('.halfonoff').removeClass('active');

 $(this).addClass('active')

})
```

Here is the Example http://jsfiddle.net/uws2g48g/

Here is code in angularJs   http://jsfiddle.net/uws2g48g/2/

Comment: And what is your problem statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/qe7vex2L/

```
.active > div:first-child,
.onoff:not(.active) > div+div
{
    background-color: #f05a43;
    color: white;   
}
```

For jQuery there is a toggleClass function you should know about. And about AngularJS, the logic can be different.